# Remove commerce item from cart

Tags: 8, commerce

I can add an order item from the cart by doing this :

```
\Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_manager')->getStorage('commerce_order_item')->create(array())
```

Is there a similar way to delete a product line from my cart ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Orders have a `removeItem` method defined on their interface. You just need to pass the loaded order item to that method, and then delete the orderitem.

```
/**
 * Removes an order item.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItemInterface $order_item
 *   The order item.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function removeItem(OrderItemInterface $order_item);
```

Answer (score 2):

Example function on how to remove all the products of specific product type from cart:

```
function _remove_all_products_of_types($typesToRemove)
{
  $orders = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider')->getCarts();
  $items = reset($orders)->getItems();

  foreach ($items as $item){
    $productType = $item->getPurchasedEntity()->get('type')[0]->get('target_id')->getValue();
    if (in_array($productType, $typesToRemove)){
      foreach ($orders as $order){
      //  $order->removeItem($item); <- wrong way!!!

      // proper way!
      $cart_manager = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_manager');
      $cart_manager->removeOrderItem($order, $item);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Function parameter is array of product type machine names (strings).

Comment: removeItem works well, but the operation needs to be saved like so : $order->removeItem($item)->save();

Comment: Works fine without saving for me ?!? But thanks anyway - maybe I'm doing that at some other step.

Comment: Yeah context is important here. I do it in a hook_form_alter().

Comment: Updated my answer above (thanks to @No Sssweat ). In old way order items are displayed well only on order edit page, but on order view page even deleted items are displayed. When removed this new, proper way it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

See how the commerce_xquantity module does this:
https://github.com/drugan/commerce_xquantity/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Entity/XquantityOrderItem.php#L318